# adjust accessibility content for UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uiaccessibility

Is it possible adjust Accessibility content for UIDatePicker?

by default(when I tap on hours' wheel) we can hear:

"2 o'clock. Picker item. Adjustable. Swipe up or down with one finger to adjust the value.”

I need to change this text.

Comment: Hi, I am having the same concern, do you have any update on this ? I need to remove the o'clock reading.

Comment: no, I did not have any update.